# Using AMPScript to update all subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to use AMPscript to let people either unsubscribe or resubscribe themselves. However, I have a 500 error message.

```
    set @unsubscribeValue=RequestParameter('unsubValue')
if (@unsubscribeValue == 'unsubscribe') then
set @Datetime = Now()
UpsertDE('Unsubscribed',1,'EmailAddress', @email_ID,'customer_id', @externalID,'UnsubscribeDate', @Datetime)
if not empty(@externalID) then
  SET @ll_sub = CreateObject('Subscriber')
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'EmailAddress', @email_ID)
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'SubscriberKey', @externalID)
  
  SET @client = CreateObject('ClientID')
  SetObjectProperty(@client, 'ID', 500009431)
  SetObjectProperty(@client, 'IDSpecified', 'true')
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'Client', @client)

  Set @options = CreateObject('UpdateOptions')
  Set @save = CreateObject('SaveOption')
  SetObjectProperty(@save, 'SaveAction', 'UpdateAdd')
  SetObjectProperty(@save, 'PropertyName', 'Status')
  AddObjectArrayItem(@options, 'SaveOptions', @save)
  
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'Status', 'Unsubscribed')

  var @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @updateOptions
  SET @updateStatusCode = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub, @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @options)

endif

set @resubscribeValue=RequestParameter('resubValue')
if (@resubscribeValue == 'resubscribe') then
set @Datetime = Now()
UpsertDE('Resubscribed',1,'EmailAddress', @email_ID,'customer_id', @externalID,'ResubscribeDate', @Datetime)


if not empty(@externalID) then
  SET @ll_sub = CreateObject('Subscriber')
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'EmailAddress', @email_ID)
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'SubscriberKey', @externalID)
  
  SET @client = CreateObject('ClientID')
  SetObjectProperty(@client, 'ID', 500009431)
  SetObjectProperty(@client, 'IDSpecified', 'true')
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'Client', @client)

  Set @options = CreateObject('UpdateOptions')
  Set @save = CreateObject('SaveOption')
  SetObjectProperty(@save, 'SaveAction', 'UpdateAdd')
  SetObjectProperty(@save, 'PropertyName', 'Status')
  AddObjectArrayItem(@options, 'SaveOptions', @save)
  
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'Status', 'Active')

  var @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @updateOptions
  SET @updateStatusCode = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub, @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @options)
  
endif
```

I'm not sure if my logic is correct, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

There’s definitely a couple of endifs missing and either you didn’t paste the whole script here, or you have skipped setting a few variables:

- @externalid
- @email_ID

Add the missing set statements for your variables, add the missing endifs and wrap the whole thing in a try/catch statement to be able to further troubleshoot your code:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
</script>

%%[
 set @unsubscribeValue=RequestParameter('unsubValue')
if (@unsubscribeValue == 'unsubscribe') then
set @Datetime = Now()
UpsertDE('Unsubscribed',1,'EmailAddress', @email_ID,'customer_id', @externalID,'UnsubscribeDate', @Datetime)
endif

if not empty(@externalID) then
  SET @ll_sub = CreateObject('Subscriber')
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'EmailAddress', @email_ID)
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'SubscriberKey', @externalID)
  
  SET @client = CreateObject('ClientID')
  SetObjectProperty(@client, 'ID', 500009431)
  SetObjectProperty(@client, 'IDSpecified', 'true')
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'Client', @client)

  Set @options = CreateObject('UpdateOptions')
  Set @save = CreateObject('SaveOption')
  SetObjectProperty(@save, 'SaveAction', 'UpdateAdd')
  SetObjectProperty(@save, 'PropertyName', 'Status')
  AddObjectArrayItem(@options, 'SaveOptions', @save)
  
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'Status', 'Unsubscribed')

  var @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @updateOptions
  SET @updateStatusCode = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub, @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @options)

endif

set @resubscribeValue=RequestParameter('resubValue')
if (@resubscribeValue == 'resubscribe') then
set @Datetime = Now()
UpsertDE('Resubscribed',1,'EmailAddress', @email_ID,'customer_id', @externalID,'ResubscribeDate', @Datetime)

endif

if not empty(@externalID) then
  SET @ll_sub = CreateObject('Subscriber')
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'EmailAddress', @email_ID)
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'SubscriberKey', @externalID)
  
  SET @client = CreateObject('ClientID')
  SetObjectProperty(@client, 'ID', 500009431)
  SetObjectProperty(@client, 'IDSpecified', 'true')
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'Client', @client)

  Set @options = CreateObject('UpdateOptions')
  Set @save = CreateObject('SaveOption')
  SetObjectProperty(@save, 'SaveAction', 'UpdateAdd')
  SetObjectProperty(@save, 'PropertyName', 'Status')
  AddObjectArrayItem(@options, 'SaveOptions', @save)
  
  SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, 'Status', 'Active')

  var @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @updateOptions
  SET @updateStatusCode = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub, @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @options)
  
endif
]%%

<script runat="server">
}catch(e){
 Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, this is not the whole code, the variables are set on top.

BTW, I'm a big fan of yours and thank you for all the things you've done such as the validator & your amazing blog.